Angular frontend root files suddenly not founded anymore inside Docker
could you please give me a hint, why this setup is not working?
My frontend docker file gives me suddenly this error. I say suddenly because it was working for a while exactly like that and even more strange is that 2 previous projects working in exact that way:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1222
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/node usr/src/app/server/main.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1045:27)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:215:24)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:5)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}


I cant understand this. In my ./frontend folder i do have all the files needed (included the server/main.js). This is mounted into the docker container and then docker tells me it cant find it?!? I have a similar nodeJS Backend which works exactly the same way (see below) and no problem here. In my point of view this error message does not make a bit of sense because all the files are living inside the mounted directory. Please tell me how i could assist you with more information & thanks for any help in advance. BR Marc
services:
   traefik:
      restart: unless-stopped
      image: traefik:latest
      ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "443:443"
         - "5000:5000" # frontend
         - "8080:8080" # backend
      networks:
         - proxy
      volumes:
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
         - ./acme.json:/acme.json
      command:
         - --providers.docker.network=proxy
         - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
         - --entryPoints.web.address=:80
         - --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
         - --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
         - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:443
         - --entryPoints.websecure.asDefault=true
         - --entryPoints.websecure.http.tls.certResolver=lets-encrypt
         - --certificatesResolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.email=mymail@web.de
         - --certificatesResolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.tlsChallenge=true
         - --certificatesResolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.storage=acme.json
   frontend:
      image: node:latest
      command:
         - node usr/src/app/server/main.js
      volumes:
         - ./frontend:/usr/src/app
      networks:
         - default
         - proxy
      labels:
         - traefik.enable=true
         - traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`my-domaine.de`)
         - traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls=true
         - traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
         - traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=5000
networks:
   proxy:
      external: true

In this nodeJS Backend, the logic is 100% the same and it is working like a charm:
backend:
      image: node:latest
      container_name: nodeJSBackend
      command: node /usr/src/app/index.js
      volumes:
         - ./backend:/usr/src/app
         - ./img:/usr/src/app/img
      networks:
         - default
         - proxy
      labels:
         - traefik.enable=true
         - traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`backend.my-domain.de`) && ( PathPrefix(`/registerNewPlayer`) || PathPrefix(`/login`) )
         - traefik.http.routers.backend.tls=true
         - traefik.http.routers.backend.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
         - traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=8080

After starting this docker, the node env can find the given index.js and start it. Perfect.
What i also did was restarting docker engine a few times, removed all existing images...did not help. I have also created a brand new VW to see if that was helping. Unfortunately not.
Even more strange is, i have 2 Projects running in the same way and none of these logs throws that the frontend files would miss. Iam so confused from docker.

How is your frontend's server/main.js file generated? Does your frontend project use Angular SSR?

it is indeed a Angular SSR build. So "npm run build:ssr" and used that files. Was never a problem before

I just generated a fresh Angular 18 project with SSR and built it. There is no such file generated like server/main.js. Are you looking for server/server.mjs?

A good first step here might be to delete the volumes: that hide the image's content.  Whatever build and install work is done in the Dockerfile gets lost when you hide it with volumes:.  (You also shouldn't need to override command: or container_name: in routine use, and most applications should be fine using only the default network and deleting all of the networks: blocks.)

@JSONDerulo i have build the project from Angular 16 and upgraded afterwards to 18. So on my side it is indeed /server/main.js

@DavidMaze i have temporary removed the volumes from docker-compose.yml. Then i start the docker and manually copy the build files into its directory. Its still the same damn error. Why for instance does the mounting of acme.json and docker.sock works without any problem? I did not experience a problem with this hiding mechanism you told me of.

Can you [edit] the question to include your Dockerfile?

@DavidMaze it's the same like above, just without the volumes. I will now try a fresh Angular SSR build just for the purpose of exclude the build itself as the error source.

So spending a whole day just testing arround I finally found a solution. The problem was somehow setting all services into one docker-compose.yml file.
Now splitting each setting into seperate folders with its own docker-compose.yml file finally solved the problem. There was nothing wrong with the Angular SSR build.
So what I have learned: never put more than neccessary into one docker-compose file and use a seperate file for each service if possible. Hope that helps.
